# Reading low contrast (3D) printed QR Codes with Android

Tags: android, image-processing, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm currently in a situation where I'm in need of a scanner that can handle reading QR codes as displayed below.

[image: Printed QR codes]

You can immediately see why this would pose a problem. As 'normal' QR codes are usually printed black on a white background (or some variation of that) to provide maximum contrast, these 'printed' QR codes offer little to none. I tried optimising these to display as much difference between the QR code and the background as possible, but this is really not in my wheelhouse. I've found some OpenCV references for applying certain filters to extract the outline, but I'm afraid the results leave much to be desired.

[image]
The last 2 images are hardly recognisable with the human eye, let alone computer vision. In an ideal situation, the last image should be completely white with an almost completely black QR code.

Concerning the actual implementation for the scanner, I've already tried the SDK's listed below but with no success of getting a response from the QR code.

1. [Mobile Vision API](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#0) (Google Play service)
2. [ZXing SDK](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)
3. [Anyline SDK](https://documentation.anyline.io/toc/platforms/android/modules/barcode.html#android-barcode-module)
4. [ZBar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android)

My question, in short, is:

Is there some type of filtering I can add that would make the QR code more readable or is there some other alternative to using filters.

Comment: Just increase the contrast even further, then invert the image. I downloaded your results image, crank the contrast to 100 in Paint.NET, invert it, and successfully scan the QR code with my phone (Mandochef)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try the following steps:

1. Change the color space to **Lab** using [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor)
2. Extract the L-channel only from the color space.
3. Use [*CLAHE*](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html) and not *equaliseHist*
4. Use the method with which you detected the QR

Answer (score 0):

After converting to luminance (or acquiring image in b&w)  you will need powerfull binarisation filter  -  I can recomend Sauvola binarisation which is implemented in javaocr library:
https://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/source/ci/master/tree/core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/javaocr/filter/SauvolaBinarisationFilter.java

( there are  android demos showcasing its usage off  preview images )

This filter works really well in noisy and non-uniform lighting condition. And it is also reasonably fast despite working over 50x50 window (actually, window size does not matter for this filter)